# User Control's Viewstate

Tags: asp.net

In some book I've seen that they save custom properties of user control like this:

```
 private int id = 0;
   public int ID
   {
      get { return id; }
      set { id = value; }
   }

   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
   }

   protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
   {
      object[] ctlState = (object[])savedState;
      base.LoadControlState(ctlState[0]);
      this.ID = (int)ctlState[1];
   }

   protected override object SaveControlState()
   {
      object[] ctlState = new object[2];
      ctlState[0] = base.SaveControlState();
      ctlState[1] = this.ID;
      return ctlState;
   }
```

My question is why can I simply store it (in setter) in viewstate like: Vistate["ID"]=id;
and then retrieve it form there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between **ViewState** (what you are talking about in your question) and **ControlState** (what is shown in the sample code):

- **ViewState** can be turned off by the user of your UserControl, by setting `EnableViewState="false"`. In that case, you wouldn't be able to restore your property's value during the next request/postback (because there is no ViewState).
- **ControlState** cannot be turned off. This means, that whatever you store in ControlState will be available during the next postback and you should therefore use ControlState for data that you absolutely need to be able to retrieve during the next request/postback.

---

See also these pages in MSDN: [ASP.NET ViewState Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) and [ControlState vs. ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)

Excerpt from the first page:

> In addition to view state, ASP.NET
>   supports control state. The page uses
>   control state to persist control
>   information that must be retained
>   between postbacks, even if view state
>   is disabled for the page or for a
>   control. Like view state, control
>   state is stored in one or more hidden
>   fields.

Comment: what do you mean "can be turned off by the user of your UserControl"?
You mean by the devloper that uses this control on his webpage? If yes, he can also remove the ControlState from the user control...

Comment: Whoever is writing the page that uses the control can set the "EnableViewState" property that can be disabled which isn't the case for the ControlState as there isn't the property to turn it off.

Comment: I still don't understand, the user is not the "end-user" that visits my site, the use is the developer that uses this control on his page. Why should he turn off the viewstate if he plans to use it for property?

Comment: Developer can also delete ControlState implementation from the user control almost as simple as setting EnableViewState to false!

Comment: "The user" is indeed the developer that puts the user control onto a page (this might be a different developer than the one that implemented the user control). So maybe the user wants to optimize the page size and therefore disables ViewState for the page. This might break the user control if it depends on ViewState, but not if it depends on ControlState.

Comment: @Martin, so if I am the developer of both page and usercontrol, I can use viewstate to save property?

Comment: Yes of course - it's up to you. If you are sure that the situation described in my comment will never occur, then there's no problem.